# How to create a "genuinely extensible" class

Tags: php, oop, abstraction

I have read a lot of articles on developing classes (I am using php), with the tag lines : 
'scalable, robust, maintainable and extensible'.

But as a beginner, I have been creating classes that are, in my words, "just abstracted". Meaning I just separated a bunch or repetitive codes and put them in a class and provide methods for accessing common tasks.

The thing is, I can't find a way to make my class extensible (I know the concept of abstract classes and such, I am even using them, but just to define methods that my other classes will follow). The thing is, **I always find myself editing the core class just to add functionlities**.

Any tips on making my class extensible? (I have googled on this and everything that pops out are explanations of abstract classes, interfaces and OOP, no discussions on pointers or some tips for making extensible classses).

Oh, btw, go easy on me, I have started "actual" oop programming 9 mos ago (the university I'm from had me going on theories on OOP, but they had us working PROCEDURALLY, because it's faster and it meets damn project deadlines, and that went on for 4 years until I graduated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the book [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)

The problem with making extensible classes, as you've discovered, is decomposing the system into useful and reusable objects.

> The task is difficult because many factors come into play: encapsulation, granularity, dependency, flexibility, performance, evolution, reusability, and on and on.

Are you trying to model some real world scenario, or are you focusing on communication / collaboration and dependencies inside your application?

Here's an example that I think kinda demonstrates what you are looking for. There are certainly a far more, far better examples:

I wanted to develop a caching system that offered my developers a simple, normalized API no matter what / where they were caching something. What do I want in a caching system (at the basic level)?

- I want to be able to cache something (set)
- I want to be able to retrieve that something (get)
- I want to be able to invalidate the cache (delete)

I came up with this:

```
abstract class MyNs_Cache
{
    abstract public function Set($key, $data, $ttl);
    abstract public function Get($key);
    abstract public function Delete($key, $ttl);
}
```

There's my extensible base class. I've then got three caching classes `MyNs_Cache_Fs`, `MyNs_Cache_Apc` and `MyNs_Cache_Memcache`

```
class MyNs_Cache_Fs
{
     ...

    public function Set($key, $data, $ttl)
    {
        // here I use fopen/fwrite/etc. to create the cached data
    }

    public function Get($key)
    {
        // here I retrieve the file from the filesystem (if it exists)
    }

    public function Delete($key) { ... }
 }
```

That's fairly straight forward. It implements the cache in terms of a FileSystem. It doesn't offer anything past my original class.

```
class MyNs_Cache_Apc
{
    ...

    public function Set($key, $data, $ttl)
    {
        return apc_add($key, $data, $ttl); // NOT A FILESYSTEM CALL
    }

    public function Get($key) { ... } // you get the idea.

    // This is specific to APC, so I add the functionality HERE
    // NOT in my main Caching class.
    public function PurgeCache()
    {
        return apc_clear_cache();
    }
}
```

My APC cache does everything I want in a caching system (set/get/delete) but it also offers the ability to clear the entire cache (something that's not useful for my FileSystem cache and impossible with memcached)

```
class MyNs_Cache_Memcache
{
    // Memcached needs a pool of servers. APC and filesystem don't.
    private $servers = array(..);

    // It also uses a memcached object.
    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = new Memcached;

        foreach ($this->$servers as $server)
            $this->AddServer($server);
    }
    ...  // we do all the standard stuff using memcached methods

    // We also want to be able to manage our connection pool
    public function AddServer($server)
    {
        $this->conn->addServer(...);
    }

    // And in some cases, we use inc/dec from memcached
    // APC doesn't have this, and it makes little sense in a filesystem
    public function Increment($key) { ... }
}
```

Now I know that I can always get one of my cache objects and just in with $obj->Get('some_key') and I'll always get a result.

Likewise, I also have access to functionality specific to what I'm currently trying to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to edit your core class to add functionality you can overwrite a method in a child class, eg:

```
class A {
 public function filter_string($str){
  return str_replace ('foo', 'bar', $str);
 }
}

class B extends A {
 public function filter_string($str){
  return str_replace ('machin', 'chose', parent::filter_string ($str));
 }
}

$a = new A;
echo $a->filter_string('foo machin'); // echoes 'bar machin'

$b = new B;
echo $b->filter_string('foo machin'); // echoes 'bar chose'
```